# Make SEO Friendly URL in Php with help of .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

**I want to make my URL from this:**
https://www.website.com/index.php?title=A1-13-05-2021

**to this:**
https://www.website.com/A1-13-05-2021

And want to access above query string param in index.php as $_GET['title'].

For this, I have written the below .htaccess code. But that's not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index?$ index.php

RewriteRule ^index/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+) index.php?title=$1
```

Can anyone please help me to know where I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rule for handling non-existing pages here to index.php file.
RewriteRule ^(A1-13-05-2021)/?$ index.php?title=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

---

---

***Generic Rules:*** In case you want to make it Generic rules then try following rules only.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rule for handling non-existing pages here to index.php file.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(A1-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/?$ index.php?title=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```